# Where does one source fonts to create logos?

Tags: fonts, logo

I'm a photographer trying to create his own logo. Naturally since it would be my own I imagine that means commercial use.

I see many directories listed as open source, and google fonts as well. However it seems google fonts doesn't currently allow print usage, only personal and commercial.

I occasionally print my photos as calendars so I imagine I need a font that allows printing.

My question is a bit broad, I apologize, I'm new to graphic design.

Comment: This might answer some parts of your question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87126/using-google-fonts-for-print-work

Comment: Where have you gotten the idea that Google Fonts doesn’t allow print usage? They absolutely do. They themselves explicitly [said so less than a month ago](https://twitter.com/bryanvicent/status/912910105179492352).

Answer (score 1):

If the font license allows only personal and commercial use, but not a word is written about printing, that's not the same as printing is forbidden. Printing is very popular way to use fonts as well personally as commercially. There can be written limitations such as "you have no right to redistribute this font (=a piece of software) itself" or "making logos using this font is forbidden" So, read the license!

Google does not write much about printing because the web is their sea for fishing. Google fonts are thus selected for good onscreen appearance, altough some of them can also be excellent for printed texts. You find easily several writings about that subject.

Established font distributors such as FontSpring, MyFont, FontZillion etc... keep available plenty of free fonts. Established distributors keep the licenses available and include them also to all downloads.

I think you will not get much answers because this answer can be interpreted to be a legal advice. Giving them is in many countries dangerous. Thus I also must write: I am not a lawyer nor a judge in a court of law. Do not take this as a legal advice. Ask from a qualified lawyer, if you need legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not restrict how you use their fonts. So yes you can use a Google font for your logo and then print it, use it on the web, etc. Whatever you want free of charge. I have personally used Google fonts for commercial and/or logo work many times.

Then, for 10-15$ you can get a [paid font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/where-do-professional-designers-go-to-look-for-typefaces/15927#15927), possibly in a different league than anything Google is offering.